# pass win32 event to .NET control

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, events

How can I consume a win32 event with a C# GUi control.

In a win32 DLL I have somehting like this:

```
e = CreateEvent(....);
SetEvent(e);
```

The event handle is exported to the .NET using a function like this:

```
HANDLE h = get_event_handle_from_dll();
```

How can I use this event handle (h) to trigger a textbox change event in my C# GUI?

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: If anything, [EventWaitHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx) but I guess you need its SafeWaitHandle property and then call WaitOne on the eventwaithandle instancce.

Comment: You need something to wait on the event. Create a thread. Wait in the event. When it is signaled, raise your gui event.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll give it a try.